# Django Login with Email or Phone Number

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to find a solution of a problem in Django for a very long time. The problem is I am trying to develop a login system than can use either email or phone number to authenticate user.

Comment: Why don't you use django allauth. It is a cool and easy-to-use  authentication system (3rd party package) in django.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, that can be done using by creating a custom user model . I have tested this. It works.

### First steps

The first thing you need to do is create a new Django project. Make sure you don't run migrations because there are still a few things we need to do before then.

After creating your new Django project, create a new app called accounts with the following command:

```
python manage.py startapp accounts
```

#### Creating the User Model

By default, the User model provided by Django has a username field, and an email field. However, we also need a phone number field. In order to add this field, we need to extend the Django user model. In the accounts app's `models.py` file, type in the following code:

models.py

```py
phone_validator = RegexValidator(r"^(\+?\d{0,4})?\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{3}\)?)\s?-?\s?(\(?\d{4}\)?)?$", "The phone number provided is invalid")


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=16, validators=[phone_validator], unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # is_translator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'full_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @staticmethod
    def has_perm(perm, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def has_module_perms(app_label, **kwargs):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Register the model with the admin

admin.py

```py
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    list_display = ('email', 'phone_number', 'full_name', 'is_active', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_active', 'is_admin')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('full_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('full_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}),
    )
    search_fields = ('email', 'full_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        is_superuser = request.user.is_superuser
        if is_superuser:
            form.base_fields['is_superuser'].disabled = True
        return form

    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

forms.py

```py
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

for login costumer in `login.html`

views.py

```py
import random
from .backends import EmailPhoneUsernameAuthenticationBackend as EoP

class UserLoginView(View):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('core:home')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = EoP.authenticate(request, username=cd['email'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged in!', 'success')
                return redirect('core:home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Your email or password is incorrect!', 'danger')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

#### Writing a Custom Backend

backends.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

User = get_user_model()

class EmailPhoneUsernameAuthenticationBackend(object):
    @staticmethod
    def authenticate(request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(
                Q(phone_number=username) | Q(email=username)
            )

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if user and check_password(password, user.password):
            return user

        return None

    @staticmethod
    def get_user(user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

#### Update the settings (3 Options)

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
# Third-party apps
'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
'accounts.backends.EmailPhoneUsernameAuthenticationBackend'
]
```

I hope your problem will be solved and others will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well that can be done using by creating a custom user model . This is the only  way known to me to achieve the result.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


def get_profile_image_filepath(self , filepath):
    return 'profile_images/' + str(self.pk) + '/profile_image.png'

def get_default_profile_image():
    return "dummy_image.png"


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image           = models.ImageField(max_length=255, 
                              upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
    hide_email              = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_profile_image_filename(self):
        return str(self.profile_image)[str(self.profile_image).index('profile_images/' + str(self.pk) + "/"):]

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

This is the custom user model and this will login via the email of the user .

You have to define in the settings.py for the user auth model .

In settings.py add this

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user_app.Account"
```

replace the "user_app" with the app in whose models.py this model is stored .

And also you need to tell to the admin to do so .

go to admin.py of the app and add this .

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from account.models import Account

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin) : 
    list_display = ("email" , "username" , "date_joined" , "last_login" , "is_admin" , "is_staff")
    search_fields = ("email" , "username")
    readonly_fields = ("id" , "date_joined" , "last_login")
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()

admin.site.register(Account , AccountAdmin)
```

Another way of achieving the result is to take email or phone number credential and password from the user and then in the views find out the username and then log the user in..

Create a form and then create a save method to do this , or diectly do it in the views.

Like this :

```
def loginView(request) : 
    if request.POST : 
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = User.objects.get(email = email)
        if user.check_password(password) :
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("home")
```