# create superuser in django custom User model with phone number as username

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a django project which I want it to have phone number as its username field. I've created an app named **accounts**, and this is the **models.py**:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, phone_number, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")
        return self.create_user(phone_number, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone_number"
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    objects = UserManager()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [phone_number]
```

And I've declared it as my user model, in **settings.py**.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "phone_number"
```

When I run `python manage.py createsuperuser`, I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'accounts.User.phone_number'
```

I can't figure out what is the problem.

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 668, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: <django.db.models.fields.CharField: phone_number>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/Desktop/custom/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/foo/Desktop/custom/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 357, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in add_arguments
    field = self.UserModel._meta.get_field(field_name)
  File "/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 670, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist(
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'accounts.User.phone_number'
```

Comment: can you please add the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @ruddra I added complete error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three problems in my code:

1. technically setting **`username`** field to **`None`** must be done before declaring **`USERNAME_FIELD`**.
2. **`REQUIRED_FIELDS`** itmes must be **strings**, not **variables**.
3. **`phone_number`** shouldn't be in **`REQUIRED_FIELDS`**, as it's **`USERNAME_FIELD`**.

So my **User model class** would be like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone_number"
    objects = UserManager()
```

---

#### Update

As Mahammadhusain mentioned, there is no need to pass `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD` in **settings.py**, as I've set `USERNAME_FIELD` in **models.py**

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy my friend just add the following to the user model

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
```

Look at this answer to know more:
[Django Login with Email or Phone Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456647/django-login-with-email-or-phone-number)

Comment: I've already done it. look at the second line of **User** model class.

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass USERNAME FIELD in `settings.py` you can pass explicitly `USERNAME FIELD` like this...

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    
    objects = UserManager()

    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

for better understanding refer to this link [here](https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/django-custom-user-model-extending-abstractuser/)